# Unity 3D-Como disponibilizar um jogo

Tags: unity3d

Fiz o meu jogo e não sei com disponibiliza-lo para outras pessoas jogarem nos seus PCs. 
E gostava de disponibilizar no meu site para downloads no «Mega» mas não sei como fazer para depois do downloads poderem jogar.
Eu sei disponibilidade um arquivo não sei e qual é que tenho de disponibilizar para outras pessoas poderem jogar.

Comment: Tiago, essa pergunta está um pouco ampla demais. Edite sua pergunta definindo em qual plataforma, se quer que seja em alguma loja ou não e outras informações que sejam válidas para podermos te ajudar.

Comment: @Tiago Francisco, seu jogo é ofiline ou online?

Comment: @Daniel-o meu jogo e ofiline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando voce faz a biuld ele cria um arquivo .exe e uma pasta "algumacoisa"data essas duas coisas a pessoa precisa para poder jogar.
A pessoa deve abrir o aruquivo .exe e pronto :).
Se entendi a pergunta é isso.